# How do you annotate Pair parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use `Pair<Int, Int>` as return type where one of the Int is annotated with `@StringRes`.

`Pair<@param:StringRes Int, Int>` gives deprecation warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. The problem is that Android's `@StringRes` is not applicable for the target `TYPE_USE` (or `TYPE` in Kotlin).

It would work if it was defined like this (java):

```
@Retention(SOURCE)
@Target({METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD, TYPE_USE})
public @interface StringRes {
}
```

Now it would work:

```
fun fooIt(p: Pair<@StringRes Int, Foo>) {}
```

There is an open issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109714923

However, it might be possible that your solution actually works, despite of the deprecation warning. I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 11):

As Lovis said, you can't do exactly that.

However if you want your signature to communicate that your parameter can't just be any `Int` but needs to be a `@StringRes`,`@IdRes`,`@LayoutRes`, etc., you could use typealiases as a workaround.

In my last project I had a file `ResourceAnnotationAliases.kt` that just defined this:

```
typealias StringRes = Int
typealias LayoutRes = Int
typealias IdRes = Int
```

So now you can give your Pair the signature `Pair<StringRes, Int>`.

Of course it will not show you an Error in the IDE when you input an Int that is not from `R.string` but at least your method signature will make clear what is expected.

Comment: amazing idea :D

Comment: Phenomenal answer!